# SELECT com 2 tabelas e mesmo campo nas duas

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde!

No meu banco de dados, tenho duas tabelas:
`imoveisvenda` e `imoveislocacao`

As duas tem o campo "dormitorio", que diz quantos dormitórios tem a casa ou apartamento, seja ele para venda ou locação.

Quero criar um `SELECT` para facilitar para quem estiver navegando no site.

Já tentei várias combinações no PHPmyAdmin, mas sem sucesso.

Como posso fazer essa consulta, para implantar em minha página PHP?

A última que tentei foi: `SELECT * imoveislocacao INNER JOIN imoveisvenda WHERE dormitorios = 3`. Mais uma vez, sem sucesso!

Já olhei algumas postagens aqui do StackOverflow, mas não consegui implantar.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

ATUALIZANDO:

Meu amigo @Ricardo, quero te agradecer pelo suporte. E, como solicitado, segue o erro que foi gerado abaixo:

```
Notice in ./libraries/sqlparser.lib.php#2477
Undefined offset: -2

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#1456: PMA_SQP_format(
array,
string 'query_only',
integer 0,
integer 2,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1574: PMA_countQueryResults(
integer 3,
boolean false,
boolean false,
string 'adimovel_imoveis',
string '',
array,
array,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2411: PMA_executeTheQuery(
array,
string '(SELECT iv.id, iv.dormitorio FROM imoveisvenda iv WHERE iv.dormitorio = 3) UNION (SELECT il.id, il.dormitorio FROM imoveislocacao il WHERE il.dormitorio = 3) LIMIT 0, 25 ',
boolean false,
string 'adimovel_imoveis',
string '',
NULL,
string '(SELECT iv.id, iv.dormitorio FROM imoveisvenda iv WHERE iv.dormitorio = 3) UNION (SELECT il.id, il.dormitorio FROM imoveislocacao il WHERE il.dormitorio = 3)',
NULL,
)
./import.php#708: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean false,
string 'adimovel_imoveis',
string '',
NULL,
string '(SELECT iv.id, iv.dormitorio FROM imoveisvenda iv WHERE iv.dormitorio = 3) UNION (SELECT il.id, il.dormitorio FROM imoveislocacao il WHERE il.dormitorio = 3)',
NULL,
boolean false,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
array,
string 'db_structure.php',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '(SELECT iv.id, iv.dormitorio FROM imoveisvenda iv WHERE iv.dormitorio = 3) UNION (SELECT il.id, il.dormitorio FROM imoveislocacao il WHERE il.dormitorio = 3)',
NULL,
NULL,
)
Notice in ./libraries/sqlparser.lib.php#2482
Undefined offset: -1

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#1456: PMA_SQP_format(
array,
string 'query_only',
integer 0,
integer 2,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1574: PMA_countQueryResults(
integer 3,
boolean false,
boolean false,
string 'adimovel_imoveis',
string '',
array,
array,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2411: PMA_executeTheQuery(
array,
string '(SELECT iv.id, iv.dormitorio FROM imoveisvenda iv WHERE iv.dormitorio = 3) UNION (SELECT il.id, il.dormitorio FROM imoveislocacao il WHERE il.dormitorio = 3) LIMIT 0, 25 ',
boolean false,
string 'adimovel_imoveis',
string '',
NULL,
string '(SELECT iv.id, iv.dormitorio FROM imoveisvenda iv WHERE iv.dormitorio = 3) UNION (SELECT il.id, il.dormitorio FROM imoveislocacao il WHERE il.dormitorio = 3)',
NULL,
)
./import.php#708: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean false,
string 'adimovel_imoveis',
string '',
NULL,
string '(SELECT iv.id, iv.dormitorio FROM imoveisvenda iv WHERE iv.dormitorio = 3) UNION (SELECT il.id, il.dormitorio FROM imoveislocacao il WHERE il.dormitorio = 3)',
NULL,
boolean false,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
array,
string 'db_structure.php',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '(SELECT iv.id, iv.dormitorio FROM imoveisvenda iv WHERE iv.dormitorio = 3) UNION (SELECT il.id, il.dormitorio FROM imoveislocacao il WHERE il.dormitorio = 3)',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Por fim, meu código completo ficou da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

                            $hostdb = "**********";
                            $userdb = "**********";
                            $passdb = "**********";
                            $tabledb = "**********";

                            $conecta = mysql_connect($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb) or die (mysql_error());
                            @mysql_select_db($tabledb, $conecta) or die ("Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados");

                            $busca_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imoveisvenda WHERE imoveisvenda.dormitorio = 3 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM imoveislocacao WHERE imoveislocacao.dormitorio = 3")or die(mysql_error());

                            if (empty($busca_query)) {
                                echo "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
                            }

                            while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($busca_query)) { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo "$dados[bancoimgthumb]";?>" class="img-responsive"> <?php
                                echo "Imóvel: $dados[imovel]<br />"; 
                                echo "Localização: $dados[localizacao]<br />"; ?>
                                Mais detalhes: <a href="<?php echo "$dados[file]";?>?id=<?php echo "$dados[id]";?>">Clique aqui!</a><br />
                                <?php echo "<hr>";
                            }
                            ?>
```

TUDO FUNCIONANDO PERFEITAMENTE! Obrigado a todos que cederam seu tempo para me ajudar! Abraços!

Comment: Qual é o id das tabelas `imoveisvenda` e `imoveislocacao`?

Comment: É um campo "id" mesmo, igual para as duas.

Comment: Tenta ai: `SELCT * FROM imoveisvenda iv INNER JOIN imoveisalocacao ia ON (iv.id = ia.id) WHERE iv.dormitorios = 2 AND ia.dormitorios = 2`

Comment: Vou tentar, já retorno.

Comment: 1054 - Unknown column 'iv.dormitorios' in 'where clause'

Comment: Coloca  o seu campo `dormitorios` na cláusula `WHERE`, nao sei como ele esta nomeado no seu banco.

Comment: É dormitório, eu corrigi, não tinha percebido... mas a consulta não retorna nada, nem mensagem de erro. Muito estranho!

Comment: Provavelmente é porque nao deve haver domitorio com valor 2

Comment: Pensei nisso também. Mudei para 3 e 1, nada...

Comment: Tentei assim: `SELECT dormitorio FROM imoveislocacao INNER JOIN imoveisvenda ON dormitorio = id WHERE dormitorio = 3` e o resultado foi: `Column 'dormitorio' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: De uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448#6448

Comment: @DenerCarvalho, vou dar uma olhada. Retornarei com a solução, sem dúvidas! Abraço, amigo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você só precisa usar o UNION ALL

```
select * from imoveisvenda where imoveisvenda.dormitorio=3 union all select * from imoveislocacao where imoveislocacao.dormitorio = 3
```

Comment: O que funcionou para mim foi o seu código, @Ronaldo. Obrigado pelo suporte!

Answer (score 1):

Eu usaria um Union em dois `selects` uma vez que não entendi como fazer o `join` das tabelas:

```
(SELECT iv.campo1, iv.campo2 FROM imoveisvenda iv WHERE iv.dormitorios = 3)
UNION
(SELECT il.campo1, il.campo2 FROM imoveislocacao il WHERE il.dormitorios = 3)
```

Da uma lida sobre o [UNION aqui](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/)

Aqui é um [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81af1/3) com o Union funcionando.

Vou colocar o código do fiddle também para manter o registro:

```
Create table imovelVendido (
  id varchar(10),
  nome varchar(10));

Create table imovelAlugado (
  id varchar(10),
  nome varchar(10));

  insert into imovelVendido values ("1","venda");
  insert into imovelAlugado values ("1","alugado");
```

Uma vez esses dados criados executa o SQL abaixo que retorna os dois registros:

```
(SELECT iv.id, iv.nome FROM imovelVendido iv WHERE iv.id = "1")
UNION
(SELECT il.id, il.nome FROM imovelAlugado il WHERE il.id = "1")
```

Comment: não deu certo. Gera um erro, até mostra os resultados, mas quando jogo na página em PHP, não mostra nada.

Comment: Qual erro esta dando?

Comment: "Foram detectados alguns erros no servidor! Por favor, olhe para a parte inferior desta janela."

Comment: O relatório é muito grande pra enviar...

Comment: Mas sem saber como vamos fazer? Edita sua pergunta e coloca o erro lá, lá vai caber. Fica formatado para todo mundo ler. Vou fazer um fiddler para testar o Union enquanto isso.

Comment: Resposta editada, não deixa de ver o link do Fiddle para entender melhor como funciona. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e36195

Answer (score 0):

No futuro, você pode melhorar sua aplicação deixando esses dados em apenas uma tabela, pois pelo que entendi a estrutura das tabelas é a mesma, você poderá criar um campo para indicar o tipo de contrato (venda/locação).
Assim suas tabelas se tornarão melhor normalizadas.

Comment: Concordo. Vou terminar o projeto, pois o tempo está bem escasso, e depois faço essa melhoria. Obrigado pela dica!